# Krasnoselskii contraction mapping

Tags: compactness, contraction-operator

*Definition:* Give metric space $(X,d)$. Mapping $f: X \to X$ is called Krasnoselskii contraction mapping if
$$\forall a,b>0, a<b, \exists k \in (0,1): a \le d(x,y) \le b \Rightarrow d(f(x),f(y)) \le kd(x,y).$$
*Problem:* Prove mappings below is Krasnoselskii contraction mapping

1. Mapping $f: X \to X$ satisfy $$d(f(x),f(y)) \le \varphi(d(x,y)),$$
   where $\varphi: [0,+\infty) \to [0,+\infty)$ is continuous,
   $\varphi(0)=0$ and $0 < \varphi(t) < t$ for all $t>0$.
2. $X$ is compact space and $f:X \to X$ satisfy $$d(f(x),f(y)) <
   d(x,y), \forall x \neq y$$

*My attempt:*

1. By setting $\psi(t)=\dfrac{\varphi(t)}{t}, t\in[a,b]$, I have proved
   that $f$ is Krasnoselskii contraction mapping.
2. I don't know how to use $X$ is compact to solve the problem.

Comment: In 2) the inequality can only hold for $x \neq y$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry, this my bad. I missed $x \neq y$ in 2). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this is false. There exist $x_k,y_k$ such that $a \leq d(x_k,y_k) \leq b$  and $d(f(x_k),f(y_k)) >(1-\frac  1 k) d(x_k,y_k)$. By compactness $(x_k)$ and $(y_k)$ converge to some $x$ and $y$ along a subsequence. Let the limits be $x$ and $y$ . Then  $ d(f(x),f(y) \geq d(x,y)$.  This contradicts the hypothesis since $d(x,y) \geq a >0$ so $x \neq y$.

Comment: Your contradiction have something wrong because $n \in (0,1)$.

Comment: @TungNguyen Right, there was a mistake. I have revised my answer.